# Get array from JQuery function to C# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I been trying to pass the output of a jquery function to my c# page code behind to do some processing and I cant figure out how to get it done properly but I know it must be possible.

my Html code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery Get Selected Radio Button Value</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                var items = [];
                $.each($("input[name]:checked"), function () {
                    items.push($(this).val());
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'WebForm1.aspx/LoadStrings',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: '{jsonString:' + items + '}',
                    dataType: 'json',
                });
                alert("You entered: " + items.join(", "));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Please select your gender.</h4>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female</label>

        <br />
        <br />

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="address" value="Kingston" />Kingston</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="address" value="Saint Catherine" />Saint Catherine</label>
    </p>
    <button type="button">Get Values</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me pass the 'items' var from the jquery function to my code behind,

```html
[WebMethod] 
public static string[] LoadStrings(string[] jsonString) { 

}
```

Comment: Do not create json object using strings concatenation.
Change `data: '{jsonString:' + items + '}'` to `data: JSON.stringify({jsonString: items})`

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in `'{jsonString:' + items + '}'`, because of string concatenation, you will get a string `{jsonString:Hello World,How are you}`, but JSON-valid string must be `{"jsonString": "Hello World", "How are you"}`.

Please use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to create JSON-valid string  `JSON.stringify({jsonString: items})`

Comment: Okay I will make the changes!